# Is there an alternative more viable of backface-visibility:hidden?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I've been using -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden to stop css transitions from flickering, but as a consequence, the text stays blurred instead of sharp(normal state).
Is there an alternative to stop the flickering transitions? because I don't think it is professional to have text blurred and buttons that show in some states blurred. I know it is because of the backface because I´ve already tested.

Comment: Can you show us a flickering example?

Comment: yes of course. but is not about the code itself .I just want to know if there is an alternative that does the same think of backface-visibility:hidden. Because I see a lot of people complain about the consequences behaviour including me .

this is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/9tfL5vzk/